# Element not allowed: enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials@http://xmlns.oracle.com

Tags: weblogic-10.x

Element not allowed: enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain in element security-configuration@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain>

**Solutions :**

enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials followed by

```
<cross-domain-security-enabled>false</cross-domain-security-enabled>
```

Adding this tag error will be resolve

Comment: are you asking, and giving the solution already ?
I don't catch the question.

Comment: Got solutions , so updated into question.